# Doctrine2 orderBy clause only accepts alias for concat column and generates wrong query for MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, orm, doctrine-orm

Doctrine2 orderBy clause accepts alias for concat column and genrates wrong query for MSSQL.

See OrderBy clause in following doctrine2 query.

```
$em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
$qb_1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $q_1 = $qb_1->select( 'reprt_abs' )
    ->addSelect( "reprt_abs.id as idd" )
    ->addSelect( "CONCAT( CONCAT(reporter.firstname, ' '), reporter.lastname) as reporter_full_name" )
    ->addSelect( "reporter.email as reporter_email" )
    ->addSelect( "CONCAT( CONCAT(prfle_usr.firstname, ' '), prfle_usr.lastname) as reported_full_name" )
    ->addSelect( "prfle_usr.email as reported_email" )
    ->addSelect( "reprt_abs.type as typ" )

    ->from( '\Entities\report_abuse', 'reprt_abs' )
    ->leftJoin( 'reprt_abs.ilookUser', 'reporter' )
    ->leftJoin( 'reprt_abs.profileUser', 'prfle_usr' );

    //List length
    if( $limit )
    {
        $q_1->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->setMaxResults( $limit );
    }

    //Sorting
    if( $orderByColumn && $order )
    {
        $q_1->orderBy( "reporter_full_name", $order );
    }

    //Filtering
    if( $filter_columns && $filterText )
    {
        foreach ( $filter_columns as $key => $filter_column )
        {
            $q_1->orWhere( $filter_column.' LIKE :word'.$key)
            ->setParameter('word'.$key, '%'.$filterText.'%');
        }
    }
    return $q_1->getQuery()->getResult();
```

If you see orderBy clause in my query you can find the I am passing alias of the column that I have selected in select clause.
It also does not allow me to pass "CONCAT( CONCAT(reporter.firstname, ' '), reporter.lastname)" directly, if I do it gives sytax error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 432: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   '('

And now issue is that with alias it generates MSSQL query but it does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sclr3 ASC) AS doctrine_rownum, 
        r0_.id AS id0, 
        r0_.type AS type1, 
        r0_.id AS id2, 
        ((i1_.firstname + ' ') + i1_.lastname) AS sclr3, 
        i1_.email AS email4, 
        ((i2_.firstname + ' ') + i2_.lastname) AS sclr5, 
        i2_.email AS email6, 
        r0_.type AS type7, 
        r0_.reporter_user_id AS reporter_user_id8, 
        r0_.post_id AS post_id9, 
        r0_.profile_id AS profile_id10 
        FROM report_abuse r0_ 
        LEFT JOIN ilook_user i1_ ON r0_.reporter_user_id = i1_.id AND (i1_.deleted_at IS NULL) 
        LEFT JOIN ilook_user i2_ ON r0_.profile_id = i2_.id AND (i2_.deleted_at IS NULL)) 
    AS doctrine_tbl 
WHERE doctrine_rownum BETWEEN 51 AND 100
```

> It give following error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid
>   column name 'sclr3'.

Now I am trapped from both the sides MSSQL and doctrine2.

**I can provide more description if anything is not clear.**

Comment: In brief, when I pass alias of selected column in orderby clause, it generates MSSQL query, which gives error at SQL-server level. Can we handle this this. I can provide more description if anything is not clear.